# Filtering my SQL to show only those records > 0

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
Master   
Detail
```

In the Master & Detail table

I get the SUM of Amount Applied in Detail and subtract it from Initial Amount in Master and display in "REMAIN"

```
select m.ID, m.Init_Amnt, m.Cur_Amnt, max(m.Init_Amnt) - sum(d.Amnt_appl) REMAIN   
from AMASTER m   
left join ADETAIL D on m.ID = d.Master_ID   
group by m.ID, m.Init_Amnt, m.Cur_Amnt
```

Is there a way to show only those where the remain in not null OR remain > 0.00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this is a filter on an aggregated result, you need a HAVING clause. Depending on your flavour of SQL, something like this:

```
HAVING ISNULL(max(m.Init_Amnt) - sum(d.Amnt-Appl), 1) > 0
```

In this, 1 is just a "magic number" to meet the `> 0` condition in the case of a null.

Answer (score 1):

A `HAVING` clause is what is needed:

```
select
   m.ID, 
   m.Init_Amnt,
   m.Cur_Amnt,
   max(m.Init_Amnt) - sum(d.Amnt_appl) REMAIN   
from AMASTER m   
left join ADETAIL D on m.ID = d.Master_ID   
group by m.ID, m.Init_Amnt, m.Cur_Amnt  
HAVING REMAIN > 0.0
```

Note some RDBMS won't allow the syntax above (it works for MySQL), using the column alias.  Instead you may need to place the full calculation into `HAVING` (SQL Server acts this way, as does Oracle)

```
select
   m.ID, 
   m.Init_Amnt,
   m.Cur_Amnt,
   max(m.Init_Amnt) - sum(d.Amnt_appl) REMAIN   
from AMASTER m   
left join ADETAIL D on m.ID = d.Master_ID   
group by m.ID, m.Init_Amnt, m.Cur_Amnt  
HAVING max(m.Init_Amnt) - sum(d.Amnt_appl) > 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

select m.ID,m.Init_Amnt, m.Cur_Amnt, max(m.Init_Amnt) - sum(d.Amnt_appl) REMAIN    
from AMASTER m    
left join ADETAIL D on m.ID = d.Master_ID    
group by m.ID, m.Init_Amnt, m.Cur_Amnt   
HAVING ISnull(max(m.Init_Amnt),0) - IsNull(sum(d.Amnt_appl),0) > 0.0
```